# How do you count all of the values in a column that satisfy your condition? (sqlite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I have a table that contains the number of workers in a set of different job fields, in all of the wards in the country. How can you find the number of wards that have more than x amount of workers (across all job fields)?
My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Table WHERE
    (SELECT SUM(working) FROM Table GROUP BY table.ward) > x)
AS working FROM Table;
```

Comment: I'm expecting a `group by` and probably a `having`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(ward) 
from
(SELECT ward FROM Table
 GROUP BY ward having SUM(working) > x) t
```

Comment: You dont need `distinct` if comming from a `group by`

Comment: Thanks. "Having" was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ward, SUM(working) 
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY ward
HAVING SUM(working) > @x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(working) AS totalWorking
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY table.ward
) workingPerWard
WHERE workingPerWard.totalWorking > x
```